# Count events that occurred in sequence

Tags: r

In my setup, every month a city might observe the occurrence of an event or not. I want to count how many of these events have occurred in a row (in sequence) within each city.

I managed to implement a script with 2 for loops one inside each other, but I have over 1500 cities and around 250 months, so it took forever for the loops to conclude. Therefore, I'm looking for some faster and more elegant solution.

```r
df <- data.frame(city = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)), month = c(1:10,1:10), event = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),                 desirable_output= c(0,0,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0))
```

In this toy example, the column "desirable_output" shows my expected output.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: `?rle` will be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, desirable_output := cumsum(event), by = .(city, rleid(city, event))]
```